# issue in identifying whether the zip file is password protected using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple web application for uploading zip files to a server. In the Javascript part I have used a try-catch block for checking whether the files are password protected(A predefined and known password) by reading the entries and catching the corresponding error.

The js library which I am using is  https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/blob/master/dist/zip.min.js.

```js
let reader;
try {
    reader = new zip.ZipReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), {
        password
    });
    const entries = await reader.getEntries();
    for (const entry of entries) {
        try {
            await entry.getData(new zip.BlobWriter(), {
                onprogress: (index, max) => {
                    zip.BlobWriter.$cancel()
                    reader.close()
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.message === zip.ERR_ENCRYPTED ||
                error.message === zip.ERR_INVALID_PASSWORD) {
                alert("Incorrect password")
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
} finally {
    await reader.close();
}
```

The above code successfully finds out if the file is not encrypted by the predetermined password. However, for some files the error statement is as below.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')

I would like to know why this happens and how to know whether the file is password protected or not.

Thank You

Comment: With `console.error(error)`  you should get more information where the error occurs. Without knowing where the error originates from it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code you proposed, for example `BlobWriter.$cancel` is not documented anywhere and does not exist actually. Also, you should call `reader.close()` only once.

Here is below how such a function could be written.

```js
const verifyZipPassword = async (file, password) => {
    const reader = new zip.ZipReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), { password });
    const entries = await reader.getEntries();
    try {
        for (const entry of entries) {
            const abortController = new AbortController();
            const signal = abortController.signal;
            const onprogress = () => abortController.abort();
            await entry.getData(new zip.BlobWriter(), { signal, onprogress });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message == zip.ERR_INVALID_PASSWORD) {
            return false;
        } else if (error.message != zip.ERR_ABORT) {
            throw error;
        }
    } finally {
        await reader.close();
    }
    return true;
};
```